Selecting the number of users who appear more than once
For simplicity, assume table has user_id and transaction_id.
I would like to see the number of users who have made more than one transactions.
I know how to do this, for example:
with cte as 
     (select 
        user_id, 
        count(transaction_id) as cnt 
     from table 
     group by user_id)

select 
    count(user_id) 
 from cte 
 where cnt>1

I'm still learning SQL and always trying to find ways to simplify my queries. So my question is, can the above be achieved using a query that has a single 'SELECT'?

please only tag the database that you are actually using, i removed the multiple versions

You do have only 1 select (because the sub-select is just a part of that 1 select.  I have rewritten this without a CTE (common table expression) here: https://dbfiddle.uk/NuQYTMTi   P.S.  Never assume that having 1 select is quicker/better/easier than not having 1 select!

Your query is fine, but can be simplified because you don't need to select the column(s) you're grouping by and you don't need to name what you're counting (when it can't be null):
with cte as (
    select count(*)
    from table 
    group by user_id
)
select count(*) 
from cte 
where cnt > 1

or refactored to the more conventional:
with cte as (
    select count(*) 
    from table 
    group by user_id
    having count(*) > 1
)
select count(*) 
from cte 


Or even simpler…
select 
user_id, 
count(transaction_id) as cnt 
from table 
group by user_id
having count(transaction_id) > 1


I was thinking the same thing, but I believe the OP asked for 'number of users who have made more than one transactions' - in other words, the answer should be a single number. You can do a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... your answer, but that's just what the other answer does.

You can use a slightly modified version of NickW's answer. Use a subquery with group by and having to get the list of users who have more than 1 transactions. Then get the count of those rows.
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM
(
   SELECT user_id FROM your_table
   GROUP BY user_id
   HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
) AS users_with_more_than_one_transactions


Count(*) vs Count(1): "There is no difference."
